# Using DAO from 64 bits application?

Tags: .net, com, 64-bit

I have a **64 bits** application from which I try to access the Access DAO API.
I only have Access 32 bits installed on my computer.

Compiling with the PIA referenced in 64 bits yields the following runtime error :

```
CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered
```

Everything works fine when compiling in 32 bits.

Is it possible to do that ?
What are my options here ?

**edit**

I narrowed it down to the fact that it is possible that MSFT does not provide a **64 bits version of the DAO**. Someone had the same issue [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.631361.17)

Comment: Have you tried to install the 64b Access driver alongside your original Access 32-bit installation, using the trick described here: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found was to desinstall Office 32 bits and install Office 64 bits, which feels wrong : I only need 64 bits for some other concerns. The datalayer should thrive to be context independant.